# Print a Image (ScreenShot) in React Native EXPO

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to take a screenshot of a component and then print it in my react native expo app. So what I am doing is taking a screenshot using react-native-view-shot and inserting it in html text and trying to print that html part using expo-print.

```
useEffect(() => {

    printMode ? viewShotRef.current.capture().then(uri => {
  
    const htmlText = `<h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong>Milan Laser Quote </strong></h3>
    <img src='${uri}'>
    <Footer<center>${uri}</center></footer>`;

    Print.selectPrinterAsync().then(obj=>{
    console.log(obj);
    Print.printAsync({ html:htmlText, orientation:Print.Orientation.landscape , printerUrl:obj.url}).then(res=>{
    setPrintMode(false), navigation.navigate('PrintSuccess', {uri})
        })
      })
    // })
 
    }) : null
}, [printMode])
```

I am not able to insert local images into html text that react-native-view-shot is giving me.

How do you think I can achieve this?

Comment: Thanks @shmili Breuer for the edit